# Sequelize 'where' condition starts with 'AND' instead of 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

This doesn't make sence. Sequelize creates a where condition which starts with an AND instead of a WHERE.

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
var query = {
            limit: 10,
            order: [
                ['id', 'DESC']
            ],
            //attributes: ['id', 'name', 'supplier_id', 'created_at', 'url'],
            include: [
                {
                    required: false,
                    model: models.termTaxonomies,
                    include: [{
                        model: models.term
                    }, {
                        attributes: ['id'],
                        model: models.taxonomy
                    }],
                    where: ["termRelationships.product_id IS NULL"],
                },
                models.image,
                models.supplier
            ],

        };
```

Which creates below SQL after executing above query with Product.findAll(query).

```
SELECT "product".*
    ,"termTaxonomies"."id" AS "termTaxonomies.id"
    ,"termTaxonomies"."taxonomy_id" AS "termTaxonomies.taxonomy_id"
    ,"termTaxonomies"."term_id" AS "termTaxonomies.term_id"
    ,"termTaxonomies"."parentId" AS "termTaxonomies.parentId"
    ,"termTaxonomies"."hierarchyLevel" AS "termTaxonomies.hierarchyLevel"
    ,"termTaxonomies"."distance" AS "termTaxonomies.distance"
    ,"termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."product_id" AS "termTaxonomies.termRelationships.product_id"
    ,"termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."term_taxonomy_id" AS "termTaxonomies.termRelationships.term_taxonomy_id"
    ,"termTaxonomies.term"."id" AS "termTaxonomies.term.id"
    ,"termTaxonomies.term"."name" AS "termTaxonomies.term.name"
    ,"termTaxonomies.term"."plural" AS "termTaxonomies.term.plural"
    ,"termTaxonomies.term"."sin_article" AS "termTaxonomies.term.sin_article"
    ,"termTaxonomies.term"."plu_article" AS "termTaxonomies.term.plu_article"
    ,"termTaxonomies.taxonomy"."id" AS "termTaxonomies.taxonomy.id"
    ,"images"."id" AS "images.id"
    ,"images"."deal_id" AS "images.deal_id"
    ,"images"."image" AS "images.image"
    ,"supplier"."id" AS "supplier.id"
    ,"supplier"."name" AS "supplier.name"
    ,"supplier"."url" AS "supplier.url"
    ,"supplier"."logo" AS "supplier.logo"
    ,"supplier"."clicks" AS "supplier.clicks"
    ,"supplier"."order" AS "supplier.order"
FROM (
    SELECT "product"."id"
        ,"product"."name"
        ,"product"."subtitle"
        ,"product"."url"
        ,"product"."prod_specs"
        ,"product"."prod_desc"
        ,"product"."supplier_id"
        ,"product"."created_at"
        ,"product"."updated_at"
        ,"product"."active"
    FROM "products" AS "product"
    ORDER BY "product"."id" DESC LIMIT 10
    ) AS "product"
LEFT JOIN (
    "term_relationships" AS "termTaxonomies.termRelationships" LEFT JOIN "term_taxonomies" AS "termTaxonomies" ON "termTaxonomies"."id" = "termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."term_taxonomy_id"
    ) ON "product"."id" = "termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."product_id"
    AND termRelationships.product_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN "terms" AS "termTaxonomies.term" ON "termTaxonomies"."term_id" = "termTaxonomies.term"."id"
LEFT JOIN "taxonomies" AS "termTaxonomies.taxonomy" ON "termTaxonomies"."taxonomy_id" = "termTaxonomies.taxonomy"."id"
LEFT JOIN "images" AS "images" ON "product"."id" = "images"."deal_id"
LEFT JOIN "suppliers" AS "supplier" ON "product"."supplier_id" = "supplier"."id"
ORDER BY "product"."id" DESC;
```

Check 6th last row (`AND termRelationships.product_id IS NULL`).

The tables for this case:

[image]

I'm trying to get all Products with their suppliers and offers, which aren't categorized yet (so which are not inside termTaxonomies for now).

It's easy to do this with a sql query, but now we are using an ORM (Sequelize), we would love to just use it completely. Anyone who can help us out?

Guess it's a bit too much to post all of my models below so I'll try to keep is short:

associations product model:

```
product.hasMany(_models.offer, {
    foreignKey: 'product_id'
});

                product.belongsToMany(_models.termTaxonomies, {
                    through: _models.termRelationships,
                    foreignKey: 'product_id'
                });

                product.hasMany(_models.image, {
                    foreignKey: 'deal_id'
                });

                product.belongsTo(_models.supplier, {
                    foreignKey: 'supplier_id'
                });
```

associations offer model:

```
offer.belongsTo(_models.product, {
                    foreignKey: 'product_id'
                });

                offer.hasMany(_models.sentDeals, {
                    foreignKey: 'offer_id'
                });

                offer.hasMany(_models.transaction, {
                  foreignKey: 'offer_id'
                });
```

associations supplier model:

```
supplier.hasMany(_models.product, {
                    foreignKey: 'supplier_id'
                });
                supplier.hasMany(_models.scraperLog, {
                    foreignKey: 'scraper_id'
                });
```

associations termTaxonomies model:

```
termTaxonomies.belongsToMany(_models.product, {
                    through: _models.termRelationships,
                    foreignKey: 'term_taxonomy_id',
                });

                termTaxonomies.belongsTo(_models.term, {
                    foreignKey: 'term_id',
                });

                termTaxonomies.belongsTo(_models.taxonomy, {
                    foreignKey: 'taxonomy_id',
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The and is the continuation of the LEFT JOIN:-

LEFT JOIN (
    "term_relationships" AS "termTaxonomies.termRelationships" LEFT JOIN "term_taxonomies" AS "termTaxonomies" ON "termTaxonomies"."id" = "termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."term_taxonomy_id"
    ) ON "product"."id" = "termTaxonomies.termRelationships"."product_id"
    AND termRelationships.product_id IS NULL

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I also figured out that it doesn't matter if you insert a required:false, or required:true. In both cases it returns the same query, except if you don't set the key "required", in that case it returns a different one. Very strange. Only for the model TermTaxonomies though, don't know why... But it works now :)